# $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\psi:V\to W$ is a linear map. Show that $\dim(\psi(U))\leqslant\dim(U)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is where I have gotten to so far, by I am under the impression that I have made an assumption with the restriction. Is this correct?

By the Rank Nullity Theorem, $\operatorname{rank}(\psi)+\operatorname{null}(\psi)=\dim(V)$.

Now $\operatorname{null}(\psi)\geqslant0\implies\dim(V)-\dim(\operatorname{Im}(\psi))\geqslant0\iff\dim(V)\geqslant\dim(\operatorname{Im}(\psi))$.

Consider now $\psi|_U:U\longrightarrow\operatorname{Im}(\psi|_U)$.

And so $\dim(U)\geqslant\dim(\operatorname{Im}|_U(\psi))=\dim(\psi(U))\blacksquare$.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the rank-nullity theorem to $\psi|_U$:\begin{align}\operatorname{rank}(\psi|_U)+\operatorname{null}(\psi|_U)=\dim U&\implies\operatorname{rank}(\psi|_U)\leqslant\dim U\\&\iff\dim\psi(U)\leqslant\dim U.\end{align}